# What function to use in CPLEX which only takes value greater than zero

Tags: function, optimization, cplex

```
costvship*(sum(m in M)(x[m][n]*h[m][p]*weight[m])- Weight)
```

which fuction to use which takes only positive value of above term

Answer (score 0):

You can use maxl

```
int v[1..2]=[-1,4];

dvar int x[1..2];

subject to
{
  forall(i in 1..2) x[i]==maxl(0,v[i]);
}

execute
{
  writeln(x);
}
```

gives

```
[0 4]
```